# Integrate GUI with OpenGL in C++

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, opengl

I need to create a GUI with a file menu and menu in which the user can input parameters. The parameters are then used for drawing rectangles in a canvas which is part of the application window. Is there a way to scale the OpenGL subwindow to just one part of the screen and the parameter input to the other? The application needs to be written in C++.

Is it possible to create a GUI with QT and draw the rectangles in the same window using OpenGL? If not, what is the common way to integrate a GUI with OpenGL? (or any other graphics library which I can use to draw rectangles from points as easy as possible)

EDIT: I am not sure If OpenGL is necessary or there is a way to paint the rectangles on the canvas like you can in Java with paintComponent().
I have never used QT before so I am not aware of its capabilites.

Comment: Did you try to google "qt opengl"?

Comment: thank you for this constructive comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use opengl window singly or use this in the common mainwindow. previous example (in first answer) show how to use opengl window in qt singly and without communication with other components of Qt (like menu, toolbar and ...). but you can add a opengl window to a mainwindow (like other widget) and use it alongside other widgets . this [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-hellogl2-example.html) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using OpenGL together with Qt is absolutely possible. There is even an [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-openglwindow-example.html) for that and Qt provides classes for a more object oriented way of using OpenGL. Have a look [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-index.html) (Section "OpenGL and OpenGL ES Integration") for more details.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to scale the OpenGL subwindow to just one part of the screen and the parameter input to the other?